# findChild возвращает nullptr

Tags: c++, qt

Какие варианты, кроме бага в Qt?

```
void ised_win::accept()
{
    m_session = m_edit->text();

    this->calculateCountofWidgetsAsync();

    if (grid)
    {
        while ( QWidget* w = grid->findChild<QPushButton*>() )
            delete w;
    }

    grid = new QVBoxLayout();
    for (int j = 0; j < m_countOfWidgets; ++j)
    {
        char buffer[3];
        itoa(j, buffer, 10);//to do
        auto bp = new QPushButton(buffer);
        grid->addWidget(bp);
    }
    vbox->addLayout(grid);
}//accept
```

Comment: `QVBoxLayout` не получает владения над `QWidget` и `QWidget` не входит в число его потомков. Более того, родителем `QWidget` может быть только другой `QWidget`.

Comment: Попробуйте создавать кнопки с родителем `this` и искать детей соответственно тоже у this. Еще советую вместо обычного `delete` использовать метод `deleteLater`. А еще у вас в коде течет память от указателя `grid`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, я думаю проще искать кнопки на самом лайауте через `count` и `itemAt`. Иначе можно зацепить что-то лишнее.

Comment: Если есть опасение зацепить лишнее, я бы вообще эти кнопки в вектор бы насовал, так надежнее всего